# Why shift left operator is slower than multiplication (C++)?

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-studio-2013

I have the below code:

```
#include "time.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned int a = 2;
    unsigned long long sum = 0;

    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= 2000000000; ++i)
    {
        //sum += i * a; --> this is faster than the below line
        sum += i << 1;
    }
    clock_t end = clock();

    cout << "time: " << ((double)end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    cout << "sum: " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For the code with multiplication, I get: 1.170 seconds.
For the code with shift left operator, I get: 1.436 seconds.

I use Visual Studio Express 2013, I compile in release mode.
My machine is running Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit.

It was interesting to me that the multiplication is faster than shifting, is this due to some optimization in the compilation phase?

Thank you.

EDIT: Using below suggestion, I disassembled the binary and it seems for the multiplication, the compiler uses some kind of loop unrolling in combination with MMX instructions. For the shifting, the shift is done directly in normal processor registers.

Comment: You can disassemble the binary and look at how those two fragments get translated in assembler.

Comment: Benchmarking is hard.

Comment: BTW, a truly smart compiler could realize that you are just computing 2000000000 * 2000000001 and avoid the loop entirely.

Comment: You should also check that the difference is reproducible across a large number of runs... it could have been some momentary system load making the multiple seem faster.

Comment: Yes, I measured at least 10 times for each version.

Comment: are you compiling for x64 or x86 ?

Comment: With clang:
$ ./test 
time: 3e-06
sum: 4000000002000000000

Comment: Impressive result from clang, might be because of aggressive optimizations LLVM does?

Comment: @user3698737: it just computes 2000000000 * 2000000001 % 2^{bits of your architecture}, which is the results of your expression. The point is that it's hard to measure the performance of hardware instructions (or even language expressions) from the running time of applications, precisely due to the wild (and sometimes incoherent, as in your case) optimizations made by the compilers.

Answer (score 0):

I have no complete answer, because i need Visual Studio Express 2013 to verify, but a can point some notes.

1. In release mode the multiplication by 2 can be replaced by << operation (by compiler), so you should check assembler output.
2. Type of "1" is "int" and "a" is "uint". It can produce different code.
3. Vectorization can be unstable and work in "*" case but not in "<<", also you should check assembler output.